# As of Feb 2015, what's the most technically secure wallet for Android?

Tags: security, android

I want a wallet on my Android phone that is rooted. I'm new to Bitcoin and I'd like to know which one is technically secure.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Canadian bitcoins". You might be located in Canada and buying them from someone in Canada (which in theory could affect your wallet choice), but these are the same bitcoins, all over the world.

Answer (score 1):

It's a difficult question to answer because an Android rooted device is never going to be secure 100%.

That being said, the safest options will be 2FA enabled wallets at a bare minimum, and multisig solutions being the best bet.

[GreenAddress.it](http://GreenAddress.it) allows for wallet functionality on par with[Blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info) but with increased security through *P2Script* using *ntimelock*. It also allows for 2FA: be sure to use TOTP (eg Google Authenticator); **do not use the same device for mobile SMS authentication** since intercepting sms on a rooted device is extremely simple.

GreenBits is a new app which integrates with GreenAddress and utilises 2FA and *P2Script* also.

Options like [BCI](http://blockchain.info) and Mycelium are not ideal for a rooted phone as the security concerns make either choice quite vulnerable to being emptied by malicious software stealing the pin code.